# What is the shortcut to go to previous search in a flat file?

Tags: shell, keyboard-shortcuts, desktop-shortcuts

Opening a flat file and giving a pattern by pressing "/", we can search for our pattern by using "n".
What is the keyboard shortcut to travel up by 1 step in that? That is, the immediate previous pattern match.

Comment: Depends a lot on which program you're using to view the file

Answer (score 1):

The key to press to go to the **previous** match of the pattern is <kbd>N</kbd>.

The <kbd>n</kbd> jumps to the **next** match instead, as you wrote.

This works in `vi`, `vim`, `more`, and `less`. (Thanks to @Kusalananda for pointing out the last two.)

Comment: Also works in both `more` and `less`.

Answer (score 1):

Most programs used as pagers (e.g. `less` and `more`) uses <kbd>/</kbd> to initiate a forward search.  You then press <kbd>n</kbd> to move from one search hit to the next, or <kbd>N</kbd> to move to the previous.

Those same programs also often supports searching backwards in the file using <kbd>?</kbd>.  Pressing <kbd>n</kbd> will in this case move to the "next" search hit, but this will be located earlier (further up) in the file. Likewise, pressing <kbd>N</kbd> would move to the "previous" search hit, later (further down) in the file.

Also, pressing <kbd>/</kbd> followed by <kbd>UpArrow</kbd> will give you the previous search term to execute again, or to modify.

The manual for the program that you use to view text files will explain this further along with all the other interactive commands that it supports.

See, for example, `man more` and you will find that it also supports marking locations in a text file with <kbd>m</kbd> followed by a lowercase letter.  Pressing <kbd>'</kbd> followed by that same letter will later bring you back to the marked location in the text.  `less` also supports this with the same keybindings.